# Integrate svg images dynamically in angularjs based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How to integrate svg images in angularjs based on condition. I am using  for this.

```html
<ng-include src="'assets/images/{{ [(titleImages | orderBy: 'findorder' | first).uniqueid] }}'"></ng-include>
```

Below is the images path.

```
$scope.titleImages =  {
  "3" : 'assets/images/valueStoryAccessIcon.svg',
  "4" : 'assets/images/brandChoiceIcon.svg',
  "6" : 'assets/images/treatmentExperienceIcon.svg',
}
```

These are my titles:

```js
$scope.titles = {
  "1": "Activation",
  "2": "Available",
  "3": "Story Access",
  "4": "Choice",
  "5": "Trade",
  "6": "Experience",
  "7": "Outcome"
};
```

What I need is:

- titleimages should be display based on the title, eg : if titleImage key is "3", it should be display in the "3"rd title "story access.
- Same as everything.

```js
if (title === "Choice") {
  imageSrc = 'assets/images/brandChoiceIcon.svg';
}
```

This is what I want. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this in angularjs. How can I integrate this, what are the possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Mapping of two different objects can be done in controller. Map 'titleImages' and 'titles' based on their keys.

```
 var mapObj = (keysMap, obj) => {

    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {

      const renamedObject = {
          [obj[key] || key]:keysMap [key]
      };

      return {
        ...acc,
        ...renamedObject
      };
    }, {});
  };

 $scope.modifiedObj= mapObj(titleImages, titles);
```

Result would be a JSON Object like this:

```
{"Activation": undefined, "Available": undefined, "Story Access": "assets/images/valueStoryAccessIcon.svg", "Outcome":undefined, "Choice": "assets/images/brandChoiceIcon.svg", "Trade": undefined,"Experience":"assets/images/treatmentExperienceIcon.svg" }
```

Then in src you can directly access based on the titles.